# TCP/IP issue C# with SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, windows, sql-server-2008, tcp

Using a C# Windows client/server application with SQL Server.

On the SQL Server machine, I enabled TCP/IP in networking and wrote inbound firewall rules to access the database.

On the client machine, I added outbound firewall rules to access server, and it worked.

But now suddenly, the client machine stops responding, and throws an error

> Can't to find mentioned TCP host

I using **windows 7 os on server machine**. and using **Windows 10 on client** machine. Is there any chance to firewall and connectivity problem for this?

Help me to solve this.

Thank you

Comment: Try to ping the server from the client.
Do you reference IP or hostname ?

Comment: I TRY WITH HOST NAME...

Comment: anyone answer this... I can't to solve.

Comment: I using windows 7 os on server machine. and using Windows 10 on client machine. Is there any chance to firewall and connectivity problem for this?

Comment: Be careful, Microsoft ends support previously about Windows 7. It's a little bit difficult to give you more information but you can : Try to ping the server from your client (to exclude network issue), check the firewall rules, ask your sys admin (if everything worked previously someone probably modify something), check if your SQL engine is well started on the server...

Comment: Thank you... I will check this... and soon I will try to upgrade w10... Thank you